# Case confusion: mit öffentlichen Verkehrsmitteln

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case, noun, dative, grammatical-number

> mit öffentlichen Verkehrsmitteln  - by public transportation

After **mit** it should be in the dative case, is it right?
Why use öffentlich**en** not öffentlich**em** there?
**Verkehrsmittel** is a neuter word. Why there is a "n" in the end?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using dative case in plural.

The word »Verkehrsmittel« literally means »traffic-device«. So one Verkehrsmittel is one singe bus, one single tramway or one single train. But more often you are talking about more of those vehicles, so you have to use the plural form.

But also when you mean the infrastructure system provided by a city or country, you use it in plural form, even if you use just one bus for a single travel:

> Ich bin heute mit den öffentlichen Verkehrsmitteln zur Arbeit gefahren.
>   Today I traveled with the public traffic-devices (plural!) to work.
>   (I know, this is bad English, but it is what you literally say in German)

But you mean:

> Ich bin heute mit dem Bus zur Arbeit gefahren.
>   Today I traveled with the bus (singular!) to work.

This is the complete table:

- Singular

  - Nominativ

    > **Das öffentliche Verkehrsmittel** meiner Wahl ist der Bus.
  - Genitiv

    > Die Sitze **des öffentlichen Verkehrsmittels** sind schmutzig.
  - Dativ

    > Ich fahre mit **dem öffentlichen Verkehrsmittel**.
  - Akkusativ

    > Ich sehe **das öffentliche Verkehrsmittel**.
- Plural

  - Nominativ

    > **Die öffentlichen Verkehrsmittel** meiner Wahl sind Busse.
  - Genitiv

    > Die Sitze **der öffentlichen Verkehrsmittel** sind schmutzig.
  - Dativ

    > Ich fahre mit **den öffentlichen Verkehrsmitteln**.
  - Akkusativ

    > Ich sehe **die öffentlichen Verkehrsmittel**.

*Verkehrsmittel* is a compound noun. It derives its grammatical properties from the last member of the compound-chain which is »das Mittel«: [declension of »Mittel«](http://www.crodict.de/nomen/deutsch/Mittel.html)

Comment: I disagree with this: *So one Verkehrsmittel is one singe bus, one single tramway or one single train*. To me, a *Verkehrsmittel* is the entirety of all vehicles of a certain type, so: all the buses form the *Verkehrsmittel "Bus"*. Only when talking about different types you'd use the plural, for example: *Die Verkehrsmittel Bus und Bahn sind sehr bequem*, aber *Das Verkehrsmittel Bus ist nicht immer umweltfreundlich*.

Comment: Also, I'd translate *Verkehrsmittel* as *means of transportation* (it's really a shame that *means* is a plural word in English...), not as a single "device".

Comment: Either way, the standard German way of putting it is using the plural. Very rarely will you have occasion to use this in the singular (_Die Buslinie 13A ist ein öffentliches Verkehrsmittel._) So mit öffentliche**n** Verkehrsmittel**n** it is.

Comment: I support the "means of transportation" translation. "Mittel" == "Means".

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it is dative case, you are right. But *Verkehrsmittel* is used in plural here. So it should be "mit öffentliche**n** Verkehrsmittel**n**".

PS. You can think of it as "*by means of public transportation*" (which is also plural).

Comment: But why Verkehrsmitteln have a "n" in the end?

Comment: Because it's dative plural.  http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Verkehrsmittel In German almost all substantives normally have an "-n" in dative plural.

Comment: I believe exceptions from the -(e)n dative plural ending are mostly (only?) loanwords, e.g., "den Autos". Note that "das/die Verkehrsmittel" is the same word in singular/plural nominative.

Comment: @user1583209 "Auto" is a short form of "Automobil". And surprisingly the dative plural auf "das Automobil" is "den Automobile**n**". Same goes for "AGB", for example. Usually you'd talk about doing something with "den AGBs", but actually you're doing something with "den allgemeinen Geschäftsbedingunge**n**".

Comment: Sure. But do you know a pure German word (not abbreviation, not loanword) which has a dative plural ending which is not -(e)n?

Comment: @user1583209 Actually no, but that's also not the question here. You're giving "Auto" as an example for a loanword that doesn't end with *-n* in dative plural. I'm saying the example is wrong, as "Auto" is not a loanword, but an "abbreviation". If you want to give examples for loanwords, *Bonbon* would be one.

Comment: Point taken, though I think "Auto" is not just a regular abbreviation of "Automobil". You are unlikely to use the word "Automobil" referring to your car for instance.

Comment: @user1583209 That's true. The general rule by the way is as follows: Dative plural is **always** built by appending an "-n" to the plural form, unless the plural form already ends with an `-s` or an `-n` already.

Comment: always by "-n"? Why not -(e)n? For example, feminine plural.  Is there a rule that tell me when use **-n** and **-en**

Comment: @EchoYang You are mixing up two things: There's a rule to build the plural form, and then there's a rule to build the dative of the plural form. I'm **not saying** to append an `-n` to the **noun** to build the dative plural. I'm saying (and so does: http://mein-deutschbuch.de/pluralbildung.html) that you append an additional `n` to the **already built plural form**, unless that already ends with `n/s`. Example: Plural form of *Frau* is *Frauen*. Dat.pl. of *Frau* is *den Frauen*, because the plural form already ends with an `n`. Plural form of *Mann* is *Männer* => dat.pl. is *den Männern*.